# React-Native image pinch-to-zoom using PanResponder (Icon as maps)

Tags: image, react-native, icons

What is the best way using react-native to set a pinch-to-zoom image, where i can place icon/button? as google maps when you are zooming icon keep position (when you zoom on the picture, icon(store/bank/metro/...) keep absolute position). Me i want this but only on one picture (1 plan)

Im trying to use [react-native-transformable-image](https://github.com/ldn0x7dc/react-native-transformable-image) but when image are moving how keep icon position. and with this library when you switch landscape you got a bug with you zoom.

To resume : is it possible to have a zoomable image where I can place elements (icon/button) on it.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Comment: No, i do not use this component anyway. Sorry, good luck.